# How to build CMake documentation with Sphinx?

Tags: documentation, cmake, python-sphinx

After checking out the CMake sources, I configured and build CMake successfully. But how do I build CMake's documentation? I have Sphinx installed.

There is no target like `make doc` and it is not obvious where I have to call which Sphinx command. I didn't find any hint in the CMake Wiki or their mailinglist archives.

Comment: If you are using CMake to build CMake you need to set the `BUILD_DOCUMENTATION` variable to `TRUE`. Check `cmake-gui` or `ccmake`. Also, I will vote to close this question since it is very narrow and should rather be asked on the CMake mailing list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the build system of the CMake project and too narrow for StackOverflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I found the answer [1]

> Configure CMake with `-DSPHINX_HTML=ON`.  Be sure you have python-sphinx
>   installed.  Point `SPHINX_EXECUTABLE` at the `sphinx-build` command if
>   needed.

Run `make`. The documentation is built in directory `Utilities/Sphinx/html`.

[1] Written by the CMake developer Brad King at the CMake developer mailing list, https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2015-September/026567.html.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to add that the resulting/new build target that is added is named `documentation` and the result is outputted to `Utilities/Sphinx/html` directory relative to your binary output directory.